# How do I get path with spaces to current executing jar with java command in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have two methods to obtain the jar path

1)

```
File file = new File(new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getName());
String filename = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
```

2)

```
String filename2 = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().substring(6);
```

The first method works perfectly for windows and Mac, but in linux, if my jar is located at `'/home/user/Documents/test folder/'`, it returns my current working directory + the jar file

Ex: If my terminal is at `/home/user/`, it returns `/home/user/MyJar.jar` even though MyJar.jar path is `'/home/user/Documents/test folder/'`.

The second method, for every operational system returns the correct path to the file but with spaces replaced by %20.

Ex: `/home/user/Documents/test%20folder/MyJar.jar`

How can I get the absolute path in Linux the same way I do for windows and Mac, and without %20 as space replacement?

Comment: If second one works best for you and you are just worried about the `%20` then you can simply add `.replace("%20"," ")` to replace all of them with spaces!

Comment: better decode the jar location rather than manually replacing %20 with space

Comment: I do not know if this is a work-around to decode that %20, but what about `java.net.url.URLDecoder.decode`?

Comment: Please show the command line you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've double wrapped your `File`'s in the first solution.

```
try {
    File f = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

(Only tested under Linux)

(I don't think the URISyntaxException will ever be thrown in production)

Comment: My code gives the absolute path of the calling jar file, whether it does or does not contain spaces. I don't understand where it doesn't solve the problem.